# Which is better between XML and SQLite to store records in Android?

Tags: android

I need to store about 100 rows records, I need to query , update, add or delete this record.
I don't know how to store the records. SQLite is a litter complex, and it seems it's a difficult to update and delete XML nodes.

BTW, I heard the xml file located in \res\xml\ folder can't be written and only can be read,right?

Comment: This question is too general. Ask about more specific problems.

Comment: That completely depends on size of data and the use case you should study about android storage techniques and then choose the best accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer SQLite. It isnt as complex as you think and not so hard to use. I think it does everything you need.
Search on Google for "Android SQLite tutorial", you will find a lot of sites with good help.

Good luck =).